# List of visa access for each country

Tags: visas, online-resources

Is there any website where you can choose "I am from Country XYZ" and then it shows you a list of countries you can e.g. go to without a visa and the allowed duration of stay. 
I know I could go to the Ministry of Foreign Affairs website of my country, but I want to see the passport status of other countries as well.

Comment: Note: you are asking the impossible (if we read literally). I assume you mean just visa free for "tourism", right? (so edit the question). Is visa on arrival not allowed?  What about Wikipedia? It has good summary, and usually updated (and link to relevant embassy). good for planing, but never trust a non official website. Before travel you should check embassy about changes and exact rules. [e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_German_citizens ]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are many. Wikipedia for example [Visa requirements by nationality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Visa_requirements_by_nationality), and [Passport Index](https://www.passportindex.org/). As stated in a comment by @Michael Hampton, always confirm the data found via such sources with an official source to check it’s not out of date.

You can also usually find this information via the Immigration / travel advice pages of many countries eg

- for US passport holders it’s [International travel country information](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/international-travel/International-Travel-Country-Information-Pages.html)
- for the UK it’s [Foreign travel advice](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice)
- Canada is [Travel advisories](https://travel.gc.ca/travelling/advisories)

These advisories typically include links to the destination country’s Immigration pages, so they are a good way to find an official source of information about the target country.

Finally, there is Timatic, the system used by airlines, which provides comprehensive information and allows you to search using a variety of criteria eg transit point(s), residency [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true) and the [IATA Travel Centre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/home.htm)

Comment: Wikipedia is the go-to source for such lists, but they can be out of date, so one should always confirm the data found there with official sources before relying on it.

Comment: A problem with the wikipedia lists is they don't sufficiently highlight countries with advance authorisation programs that the politicians refuse to call visas.

Comment: @PeterGreen do you mean all the ETA/ESTA/eVisitor etc? Those are usually well indicated on the Wikipedia pages. If you meant something else, can you give an example?

Comment: They are indicated in the text, but the coloring on the maps makes no distinction between countries that are truely free of visa's and visa-like things and countries that require some kind of advance authorisation.

Comment: @PeterGreen Not sure what you mean, eg for Argentina the map distinguishes between ID card travel, Visa not required / ESTA / eTA / eVisitor, Visa available both on arrival or online, Visa on arrival, eVisa, Visa required. Covers all bases as far as I can see.